# Quest editor in java for big game

Tags: java, triggers, prolog, game-engine

It's a very specific problem I have:

I'm working on a text-based RPG, where the main work is to implement an editor, that gives the possibility to add NPCs, Items and place them on the map (...) without any knowledge about programming.

All of these things work fine with doing some SQL queries and the whole thing already works. Now I'm working on quest editing. My basic concept is, that every time the player enters a command, a database entry for the specific string is queried, that's linked to a set of conditions and actions, which have unique IDs. Those are queried in the java code, where a specific condition (e.g. that the players money equals 100) has a part of code that returns the result. This means, that hundreds (or more) IFs have to be passed, each time a command is entered - same with the actions according to the command. I'm not even sure if that is the right way (If anyone has a propose to this, feel free to post).

The point is now, that quests basically consist of quest stages, which also have conditions to be enabled and actions, performed when enabled. That means, that also with each entered command, all of these queries have to take place. I thought about using some kind of trigger, but I don't have a good idea how to implement it, because I don't really want to edit java code out of this editor. I also considered using prolog, but also in that case I'd have to add triggers into java code I guess.

I know that this is a little bit hard to handle in a forum like this, but if anyone has a suggestion, I'd be really glad.

**EDIT:**

As suggested in a comment, I'd like to shorten the whole thing: If any command (out of houndres or thousands) could trigger one particular quest/quest stage (out of thousands) and these triggers should be set with an editor, what's a proper way to implement that?

Comment: I'm interested in helping with your problem, but am having trouble formulating your problem into an answerable question. Could you try to come up with a one-sentence question that, when answered, will achieve your goals? I have a context of what's going on in your system, but I don't see your actual problem.

Comment: having lots of actions that you want to trigger when a specific composition of conditions is met sounds like a good fit for drools (https://www.jboss.org/drools/). its a bit of a learning curve, but can hols thousands of "facts" in memory (every action the player takes or decision he makes can be represented as a "fact") and lots of "rules" waiting to trigger when a specific combination of facts is met.

Comment: @radai That sounds to me as if it is very similar to prolog, I mentioned in my question, but I'm not sure if I can achive this without editing the java code from the editor. But thank, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: drools provides a language for writing these rules and allows you to customize the language to make it more accessible to non-programming users (thats one of its stated goals - let non-developers write logic). it can also add/remove/modify these rules on the fly. thus its quite possible to implement the logic behind a typical quest without writing java code

Comment: I read it three times and did not understand what exactly was your question. If your problem is to interpret the command, then just build a syntatic tree for it and then visit/iterate/transform the syntatic tree in some way to trigger your event.

Comment: Okey, I took a short look and it seems to be exactly what I need. Thanks a lot - is there a way to mark comments as the most helpful answer?

Comment: Well, I think that no comment here really answers your question. If they did, people would post answers, not comments.

Comment: +1 for Drools, it answers the question and does what is required.  It also supports various languages for writing rules and actions in, if memory serves.

Comment: @Grochni - no, you cant mark a comment as an answer, but i've summed up what i said so far as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reasoning over lots of facts and triggering actions when a set of facts matches specific conditions is a good match for [drools](https://www.jboss.org/drools/).

you could represent every action/decision that the player has made as a fact, which you could insert into a drools knowledge session.

in that session you could store all of your "triggers" as drools rules, which will fire when a collection of facts in memory match the condition.

drools supports dynamic addition/removal/editing of rules and is explicitely targeted at allowing non-developers to write logic using a simpler rule language.

the specific part of drools to start with is the core - [drools expert](https://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-expert.html)

Comment: There is even a graphical UI for creating and editing rules called Drools Guvnor which may help solve the issue of needing an editor.

Comment: yes, although thats usually installed as a separate stand-alone server. might be a bit too heavy as-is, and i've never tried using it embedded (which is what you'll probably want for a stand-alone game). there's also an eclipse plugin that will allow you to visualize and debug your rules.